# Where Am I Going Wrong on this Curvature Problem?

Tags: parametric, curvature

Massively deviating from the given answer on this one, have no idea what's going on. I'm sure that I'm using the correct formulas, but the answer provided is very different from what I come up with.

Find the curvature of the following function:

x = 5cos(t) ; y = 4sin(t) ; t = $pi$/4

Formula for curvature is k = (**v(t)** x **a(t)**)/$v^3$

**r**(t) = 5cos(t)**i** + 4sin(t)**j** + 0**k**

**v**(t) = -5sin(t)**i**  + 4cos(t)**j** + 0**k**

**a**(t) = -5cos(t)**i** - 4sin(t)**j** + 0**k**

**v(t)** x **a(t)** = $20sin(t)^2$ + $20cos(t)^2$ **k** = 20**k**

|**v** x **a**| = 20

That's the numerator, now the denominator:

v = |**v**| = $\sqrt{(-5sin(t))^2 + (4cos(t))^2}$

= $\sqrt{25sin(t)^2 + 16cos(t)^2}$

With t = $pi/4$:

v = $\sqrt{25sin(pi/4)^2 + 16cos(pi/4)^2}$

= $\sqrt{27.51}$ = $5.25$

So now I have v and |**v** x **a**|, so I should be ready to solve:

$20/5.25^3 = 0.138$

Now here's what the book shows:

$40\sqrt{82}/1681 = 0.215$

I can't even begin to fathom where these numbers are coming from, but they are clearly obtained much differently than what I'm doing. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your calculation of the denominator (you wrote down the same error in the numerator as well, but computed it correctly there).

Note that |**v**| = $\sqrt{(-5sin(t))^2 + (4cos(t))^2} = \sqrt{(-5)^2(sin(t))^2 + (4)^2(cos(t))^2} = \sqrt{25sin^{2}(t) + 16cos^{2}(t)}$ and **not** $\sqrt{25sin(t)^2 + 16cos(t)^2}$. So by this, $v = \sqrt{20.5} = 4.5277$ approximately. And so, $\dfrac{20}{(4.5277)^3} = 0.215$ approximately, which is the same as the answer in your book.

Comment: Jobin, thank you, but I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. $\sqrt{25sin^{2}(t) + 16cos^{2}(t)}$ and $\sqrt{25sin(t)^2 + 16cos(t)^2}$ are just two syntaxes of the same concept, aren't they? As in $25sin^{2}(t)$ = $25sin(t)^{2}$ = $25(sin(t))^2$? That's the calculation I've always used before, and it usually seems to work.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see what you mean. I entered the calculation into my calculator as $25sin(pi/4)^2$ thinking it was equivalent to $25(sin(pi/4))^2$, but on further review no, of course it will apply the square before taking the sine. Thank you, that was a stupid calculator error that was really messing me up.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :)